# How to get xPath of an element, and retrieve the element again from the xPath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to create an application where a user can store annotations within the browser.

To figure out where the user created annotations within the document, I'm trying to store the xpath and the offset of the selected text.

I've searched around and it seems there are many examples of retrieving an element from xPath string, but not good examples of finding xPath from a DOM element.

Here's what I've tried:

```js
//Find xPath and pass the object
var range_obj = {
  start: getXPathForElement(range.startContainer, range.startContainer.ownerDocument),
  end: getXPathForElement(range.endContainer, range.endContainer.ownerDocument),
  startOffset: range.startOffset,
  endOffset: range.endOffset
};
```

where getXPathForElement looks like this:

```js
function getXPathForElement(el, xml) {
  var xpath = '';
  var pos, tempitem2;

  while (el !== xml.documentElement) {
    pos = 0;
    tempitem2 = el;
    while (tempitem2) {
      if (tempitem2.nodeType === 1 && tempitem2.nodeName === el.nodeName) { // If it is ELEMENT_NODE of the same name
        pos += 1;
      }
      tempitem2 = tempitem2.previousSibling;
    }

    xpath = "*[name()='" + el.nodeName + "' and namespace-uri()='" + (el.namespaceURI === null ? '' : el.namespaceURI) + "'][" + pos + ']' + '/' + xpath;

    el = el.parentNode;
  }
  xpath = '/*' + "[name()='" + xml.documentElement.nodeName + "' and namespace-uri()='" + (el.namespaceURI === null ? '' : el.namespaceURI) + "']" + '/' + xpath;
  xpath = xpath.replace(/\/$/, '');
  return xpath;
}
```

and this code gives a very long weird looking text like this: (which i don't think is really a correct xPath).

> "/*[name()='HTML' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml']/*[name()='BODY' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'][1]/*[name()='P' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'][1]/*[name()='SPAN' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'][4]/*[name()='SPAN' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'][2]/*[name()='#text' and namespace-uri()='undefined'][0]"

But in Chrome Inspect Element, it gives some clean string like this:

> //*[@id="tinymce"]/p/span[2]/span[2]/strong

Can anyone help me retrieve xpath of an element from a document and then find the element from the xpath later on?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use Saxon-JS then you can use the XPath 3.0 function fn:path() which is designed expressly for this purpose.